# Id generation PostgreSQL hibernate XML C#

Tags: c#, sql, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

I cannot solve this problem, I have tried almost everything, but as you can quess - nothing.

This is my xml mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" assembly="Test" namespace="Test.Model">
  <class name="Visitor" table="visitors" dynamic-update="true" >
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="Id" column="id" type="long" >
      <generator class="sequence" >
        <param name="sequence">visitors_id_seq</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column ="name"/>
    <property name="Age" column ="age"/>
    <property name="Gender" column ="gender"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

It works fine ,but when I try to insert new recoder it gives me an error

> could not insert: [Test.Model.Visitor#13][SQL: INSERT INTO visitors
>   (name, age, gender, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]

My model class is

```
public class Visitor : HumanEntityBase
{

}

public class HumanEntityBase : EntityBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual char Gender { get; set; }
}
  public class EntityBase
    {
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried different types of class like native, identity but nothing helped.

And SQL is following

```
CREATE TABLE visitors ( name text,
                       age integer,
                       gender character varying(1),
                       id bigserial NOT NULL,
                       CONSTRAINT visitors_primary
                       PRIMARY KEY (id) ) WITH (   OIDS=FALSE );
ALTER TABLE visitors   OWNER TO postgres;
```

Sequence

```
-- Sequence: visitors_id_seq

-- DROP SEQUENCE visitors_id_seq;

CREATE SEQUENCE visitors_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1 
    MINVALUE 1 
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    START 3
    CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE visitors_id_seq  
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Please help with this problem, I have no idea what to try more .

**EDIT**

Is there anyway not to insert ID ? I think it will work, but I cannot figure out how to do this, only retrieve ID but not insert generate and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.
The main issue was that I have tried to insert empty value

```
INSERT INTO visitors (id, name, age, gender) VALUES (nextval ('visitors_id_seq'), (('фыв22')::text), ((2112)::int4), ((' ')::text)) returning id
```

This doesn't work from NPgsql , but works great from pgAdmin sql query.
I have accidently found this issue, also I have had to modify my mapping file a little bit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" assembly="Test" namespace="Test.Model">
  <class name="Visitor" table="visitors" dynamic-update="true" >
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="Id" column="id"  type="long">
      <generator class="identity">
        <param name="sequence">visitors_id_seq</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column ="name"/>
    <property name="Age" column ="age"/>
    <property name="Gender" column ="gender"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```